# Multiprocessing not returning all values

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-itertools, brute-force

This may be a very easy question but definitely worn me out. To use multiprocessing, I wrote the following function thread() which parallelizes the function crack. Function Crack returns multiple lists inside a list. But when I use thread function it does not return every value. How can I fix it?

```
UPPER_ALPHA = ['Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P', 'A', 'S', 'D',
               'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M', ]

def crack(UPPER_ALPHA):
    GEN = list(itertools.product(UPPER_ALPHA, repeat=4))
    return GEN

def thread(w_input):
pool = mp.Pool()
results = pool.map(crack,UPPER_ALPHA)
print(results)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: You haven't implemented, or even described, the brute forcing you're trying to do in a single-threaded context; you're asking us to: 1) Guess what you're doing 2) Implement it 3) Parallelize the implementation. Even #3 alone is too broad a request; with all three of them, you're basically asking us to do your homework from scratch, without even providing the instructions. If you don't even know where to start, talk to your teacher. If you come up with something that seems like it should work, but doesn't, post a new question with a [MCVE] for people to assist with.

Comment: No this is not a homework. I just asked how to convert this single threaded context into multi threaded.btw I forgot to tell that how can I split the work for each workers

Answer (score 0):

Are looking for something like this result ?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process
from functools import partial

#Function for single process
def function(rep, val):
    return (val,) * rep

# Function for handling multiprocessing
def handler(function, data, rep, workers=4):
    func = partial(function,rep)
    with Pool(workers) as pool:
        r = pool.map(func, data)
    return r

data = ['a','b', 'c']
GEN = handler(function, data, 2, workers=4)
print(GEN)
```

Result:

```
[('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'), ('c', 'c')]
```

Comment: sorry i changed the question

Comment: Can u explain what is happening in variable func

Comment: func is a wrapper of  the function. It only accepts one input argument, where function accepts two argument. partial () allow us to reduce parameters of a function and set fixed values for more limited function.

Comment: ok but how can I use this in my function. I think u misunderstood the question.